# structs for IP, TCP and VLAN

Tags: c, linux, ethernet

I've recently inherited an almost 7 year old codebase, including a library with public headers with definitions of IP-, TCP, VLAN-structs and a shitload of defines (like `#define TCP_NODELAY 1`).

I tried to look for headers with these structs but I couldn't find anything (this is primary on linux, but also various BSD-variants). Surely there must be headers for this already?

I think `net/ethernet.h` helped with all the defines.

**EDIT**: Found most of the structs I'm looking for:
`struct tcphdr` in `netinet/tcp.h`
`struct udphdr` in `netinet/udp.h`
`struct ip` in `netinet/ip.h`

Does anyone have any clue about a struct with the vlan-header? (ether_vlan_header?)

Comment: I don't want to accept "answers" not answering my question, or faulty solutions.

Comment: @ext: As a sample, the answer to your current question is simply "yes". Would you accept that? If not, then rephrase the question to something that *can* be answered to your satisfaction.

Comment: It's not that I don't get your point, but look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412832/python-line-editing-telnet-server for instance, only 1/3 answers is briefly related to my question (other is a _client_ library and one is a semi-shell). I've asked 6 questions in total. And English is not my native language.

Comment: It doesn't appear to me that you've made any attempt to clarify what you want in that old question. I still think the fault is yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
find /usr/include -type f | xargs grep TCP_NODELAY
```

where `TCP_NODELAY` is the symbol you're looking for.

You can look for all symbols at the same time by writing them to a file (one per line), and using `grep -f FILE`.

Comment: Yes, I used something similar to find TCP_NODELAY, but did not find the struct literally called `ip` (to many matches to find anything) or `ether_vlan_header` (no matches)