# Ruby line editing telnet server

Tags: ruby, sockets, telnet, libreadline

I am implementing a little telnet server in Ruby. The problem I'm currently facing is that I want to add readline support so that I can have tab-completion and command-line history support. I have looked at the [Readline](http://bogojoker.com/readline) library, but it seems as though it will only work via stdin. Is there any way of doing this in Ruby (I noticed the solution for [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412832/python-line-editing-telnet-server))?

Comment: Sorry, are you tried to implement readline on the server? I believe readline is something implemented on the client-side.

Comment: Jip, that is my issue at the moment. Readline only works with stdin (thus, only client-side). I want to know if it is possible to get readline working over telnet so that I can get auto-completion etc. for the server-side commands that are exposed by my telnet server.

Comment: I don't think readline will work on anything other than stdin. Do you expect users to connect using the standard telnet client? I'm actually not sure whether telnet supports tab completion. I think the most straightforward way would be to simply implement your own client and add readline support with tab completion there.

Comment: ruby Readline has .input= and .output= methods, which are, according to the docs, supposed to set the file to input/output from. They seem to be ignored on my 1.9.2 install, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by plumbing a pipe into readline. Here's an example using the `while` loop from the ri readline documentation that just sends `command 1`, `command2`, `command 3` to readline.

```
require 'readline'

rd, wr = IO.pipe

(1..3).each do |i|
  wr.puts "command #{i}"
end
wr.close

Readline.input = rd
while buf = Readline.readline('', true)
  p Readline::HISTORY.to_a
  print("-> ", buf, "\n")
end
```

Output:

```
["command 1"]
-> command 1
["command 1", "command 2"]
-> command 2
["command 1", "command 2", "command 3"]
-> command 3
```